# Can i run authentication server in firebase hosting?

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-authentication

I am planning to run authentication server in firebase hosting . So that it will server JWT for login the users .

My choice of language and framework is java and spring boot .

Now i have to explore on two possibilities  .
  (i) Running Auth server on firebase hosting ?
  (ii) Running the tech stack i have chosen ?

Any help / direction is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting serves static files only. It does not interpret the contents/code in the files that it hosts. So there is no way to run your own Java code on Firebase Hosting.

You could run the Java code on [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) and then use Firebase Hosting as a front-end for that by [connecting them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run).